# Cloud Function Unable to SSH into Virtual Machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, google-cloud-functions

My goal is to trigger an SSH login to my GCP instance and start my node server when a website is hit. My function crashes early in the process.

```
POST500736 B336 msGoogle-Cloud-Functions https://function-name
Reading private key file contents:
Error starting Node.js server on VM tr-instance-1: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

While this sounds like the SSH key doesn't exist, it indeed does.

- I have recreated the keys multiple times and retested.
- I am sure the key is in RSA/PEM format.
- I have appropriate (600) permissions on the key file.
- I have confirmed that I am using the correct VM external IP.

I believe it's not making it to the key location correctly because it is failing to connect to the VM via SSH. In other words, the error is perhaps misleading.

I am able to automatically log into my instance via SSH through the VM console. However, when I try to log in via a manual SSH (i.e., using the private key from my local computer to SSH in), I get an error that I'm not able to upload my key file.
`Failed to upload your file. nf`
This error remains when I recreate the keys and use a brand new one from my local machine. It is simply the RSA private key with limited text. I don't know if this is a separate issue or is related to my function not connecting to my SSH. It seems odd that I can't use this key, and the error message is not helpful.

Here is my node.js function code. The package.json has firebase-functions and node-ssh.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { NodeSSH } = require('node-ssh');

const startServer = async (instanceName) => {
  try {
    const ssh = new NodeSSH();

    const fs = require('fs');
    const privateKeyPath = '/home/username/.ssh/ai_keys';

    console.log('Reading private key file contents:');
    const privateKeyContents = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf8');
    console.log(privateKeyContents);

// Continue with the SSH connection code


    // Connect to the VM via SSH
    await ssh.connect({
      host: 'external.IP.here', // VM's external IP
      username: 'my_username', // VM's SSH username
      privateKey: privateKeyPath, // SSH private key file path
    });

    // Check if SSH connection is established successfully
    if (ssh.isConnected()) {
      console.log(`SSH connection to VM ${instanceName} established successfully.`);
    } else {
      console.error(`Failed to establish SSH connection to VM ${instanceName}.`);
      return false;
    }

    // Run the Node.js server start command
    await ssh.execCommand('cd /user/project_dir && node server.js');
    
    // Disconnect the SSH connection
    ssh.dispose();

    console.log(`Node.js server on VM ${instanceName} started successfully.`);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error starting Node.js server on VM ${instanceName}:`, error);
    return false;
  }
};

exports.startServer = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Set CORS headers to allow requests from a specific origin
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://example.com');

  // Check if the request method is OPTIONS (pre-flight request)
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    // Set CORS headers for pre-flight requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.status(204).send('');
    return;
  }

  const instanceName = 'my_instance_name'; // instance name

  const success = await startServer(instanceName);

  if (success) {
    res.status(200).send('Node.js server started successfully.');
  } else {
    res.status(500).send('Error starting Node.js server.');
  }
});
```

I am fairly new at this, so please don't overlook a basic and/or stupid mistake! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming that /home/username/.ssh/ai_keys exists on the Cloud Functions instance running your code.  It almost certainly does not.

If you want some file to be available to code running in Cloud Functions, you will have to arrange for that file to be part of your deployment.  That means it's going to have to be in the folder along with your source code.  Read the documentation for the `--source` flag for [`gcloud functions deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy).

You can read those files at runtime relative to the current working directory (don't try to code a full path to that file - you don't necessarily know what that's going to be.

Comment: I definitely don't want the keys to be looked for on my Cloud Function's instance, I want it to be read on my VM that I am trying to SSH into. This line `const privateKeyContents = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf8');` is reading from the Cloud Function instance?

Comment: Is your code not reading that file before the ssh happens?  Where else would the read come from, if you track the execution of the code line by line? `fs.readFileSync` must be reading from the local filesystem of the code running in the function.

Comment: I see, thanks very much for the help. I always wondered how the function could be accessing my private keys without having access to my VM first. It looks like I will need to create a GC Secret Manager for the key and go from there. Thanks again!